# Typo3 is ext_tables.php still relevant in v8+?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

I'm a Typoscript newbie and currently following tutorials to develop extensions. The documentation seems a little outdated so I#m muddled up in a few places, specifically:

--ext_tables.php

--configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

--configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php

...from what I can tell most of the ext_tables.php code now resides in the configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php file (eg. the ::registerPlugin call). But where do the "::addStaticFile" calls now reside? Some say ext_tables.php, others say configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php ??

Do you think they will eventually deprecate ext_tables.php?

The T3 documentation site could do with updating the examples as and when things change. Very confusing for newbies.

thanks all

Comment: can this help you? https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.5/Breaking-78384-FrontendIgnoresTCAInExtTables.html

Comment: Thanks, Yes that helps a lot

Comment: updated link: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/latest/Changelog/8.5/Breaking-78384-FrontendIgnoresTCAInExtTables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradually, the root of an extension folder will be cleaned up. Besides the TCA Override feature and the deprecation Riccardo showed you, TYPO3 v9 also simplified the database table creation, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/latest/Changelog/9.3/Feature-85160-AutoCreateManagementDBFieldsFromTCACtrl.html.

When it comes to the registration of your static TypoScript files just check other core extensions how they handle it. See for example the form framework: https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/form/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php. This is best practise nowadays. Furtermore, use .typoscript as file extension, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.7.x/Feature-78161-IntroduceTypoScriptFileExtension.html. In addition, .tsconfig shall be used for UserTS and PageTS, see https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.5/Breaking-78384-FrontendIgnoresTCAInExtTables.html.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't get why registerPlugin(), addPlugin() and addPiFlexFormValue() are added to the Overrides/tt_content.php page. Logically I would assume anything inside this file is amending the tt_content table, and not registering utilities. I hope they consider moving any plugin registrations to a more obvious location in the future.

Comment: I am sure additional cleanups will follow in this area. There is still a lot of legacy code around. IMHO the next big thing should be getting rid of all the redundant registration for a new field: add it to the .sql file, add it to the TCA, add it to the model... I am pretty sure, v10 will improve a lot in this field. Stay tuned :)